# "Go to Definition" missing on VSCode on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I develop on Javascript with VSCode, on Ubuntu 19.04. When right clicking on a function or variable, "Go to Definition" line is missing. Also by clicking "Go -> Go to definition" on nav bar does nothing. Also binded a key to said function but it still not works. Not sure if there are any VSCode logs I can look at.

When using VSCode on Windows 10 with same project, the "Go to Definition" function works as expected.

Comment: I think you should file a bug for this. There's not much anybody here can do about this.

Comment: I will, thanks for the suggestion